# SSL certificate on Heroku

Tags: ssl, heroku

I have one domain purchased from GoDaddy.

lets say it is www.example.com, I have purchased wild card SSL certificate from GoDaddy for this domain.

This domain is pointing to one of my app on Heroku. When I type http://www.example.com, it is working fine. But when I type https://www.exapmle.com,

It says "web page not available" and error code is:

```
 "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED".
```

So do I need to add SSL certificate on Heroku too? How https will work on my site when it's pointing to Heroku? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upload your SSL certificate to Heroku with its CLI command `heroku certs:add`. Probably you also need to activate an SSL Endpoint addon ($20/month) and set your DNS CNAME pointing to it.

See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint#provision-the-add-on for details, and subsequent sections.